# Relative URL for Background Image

Tags: css, flexslider

I need to have a relative url for the navigation arrows in a Flexslider Slide Show.

How do I rewrite the following css, so that I can apply it on different sites?

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin: -20px 0 0; 
    display: block; 
    background: url(https://example.com/images/slideshow-buttons.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; 
    z-index:3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's relative to where the `style.css` file is located

If the css file is in the root or another folder.

If it is `example.com/style.css` it would be:

`background: url (images/slideshow-buttons.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

If it is `example.com/css/style.css` it would be :

`background: url (../images/slideshow-buttons.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

Comment: Thanks @Miro. Now I know why I'm having so much trouble. In a number of cases, I've been trying to make this work on a test site that is a sub domain. It's also a joomla installation, so the css files in a folder for a particular template. In this case it looks like this: example.com/testing/templates/template1/css/flexslider.css . Now would I write it for this example?